# how to connect rais data by basedosdata package

Tags: r

```
Error in `basedosdados::bdplyr()`:
! The table basedosdados.br_me_rais.microdados_vinculos doesn't have a valid name or was not found at basedosdados.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

this problem is appearing,  how to solve it?

I can't connect to the link rais database